# PReLU with variable input size

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

How can I use the `PReLU` activation function with an variable input size?

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import PReLU

X = Input(shape=(None,None,1))
conv1Y = Conv2D(filters=49, kernel_size=7, name='conv1')(X)
conv1Y = PReLU()(conv1Y)
```

The code above yields

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and
>   'NoneType'

Comment: Have you tried `conv1Y = Conv2D(filters=49, kernel_size=7, name='conv1', activation=PReLU())(X)`?

Comment: Yes: `UserWarning: Do not pass a layer instance (such as PReLU) as the activation argument of another layer. Instead, advanced activation layers should be used just like any other layer in a model.` ... `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

Answer (score 0):

Use PreLU(shared_axes=[1,2]) so shape is computed on compilation.